# How to resize font in table (by percentage)

Tags: tables, fonts, fontsize

I want to change the font size in this table by using percentage (not just a number of size)
for example, I want to reduct 50% of font size, I just type 0.5 to reduce 50%

Or Latex had a rescale command on Table?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
\hline
\textbf{A type.} & \textbf{B type}     &  \textbf{C type}  & \textbf{D type}  \\ \hline
A &ABCD  &  1 & 3   \\ \hline
B &ABCD  &. 2 & 4  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}%

\caption{\label{font-table} Test table.}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
```

Thank you for answer

Comment: you can scale tables but it makes inconsistent fonts and rules so isn't ever recommended.  if your document default is 10pt then you can simply use `\tiny` (which is 5pt) or use a custom size such as `\fontsize{5.5pt}{7pt}\selectfont`

Comment: Following up on @DavidCarlisle's approach, you can declare a length `\txtsize` and set it to, say, `11pt`, on your preamble and use something like `\fontsize{0.5\txtsize}{0.75\txtsize}\selectfont`; I don't know if `0.5\normalsize` would work as a parameter inside the above command. Another option is the `\relscale` command from [the `relsize` package](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/relsize/relsize-doc.pdf).

Comment: DavidCarlisle and Óscar Guajardo Thank you so much for answer